# How to get Colors from Gradientrawable?

Tags: android, gradientdrawable

How it is possible to get `Gradientrawable` colors set by `setColors(@ColorInt int[] colors)` ?

Any help will be appricated.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference GradientDrawable.java then make some proper modification for result as required.

```
    public class ColorGradientDrawable extends Drawable {
        ...
        private int mColor; // this is the color which you try to get
        ...
        // original setColor function with little modification
        public void setColor(int argb) {
            mColor = argb;
            mGradientState.setSolidColor(argb);
            mFillPaint.setColor(argb);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
```

// that's how I get the color from this drawable class

```
        public int getColor() {
            return mColor;
        }
        ...
```

// This is same as GradientState, just make some proper modification to make it compilable

```
        final public static class GradientState extends ConstantState {
            ...
        }
    }
```